# R: Add non-pch symbols to a map (polygon layer)

Tags: r, plot, maps, gis, geospatial

I use R as a GIS here, to create a map. It's a monochrome (black/white) site plan. However, I want to distinguish forests from other areas using [these open triangular symbols for coniferous forests](https://www.doris.at/themen/basiskarten/pdf/Legende_OEK50.pdf) that are quite common in cartography in the german speaking world.

A bit of research led me to the `my.symbols` function from the `TeachingDemos` package. I understood one could write a function plotting the desired symbol in a `xlim = c(-1,1)`, `ylim = c(-1,1)` plot and then use `TeachingDemos::my.symbols` to add this symbol as with the `points` function to a plot. My plan was to give `TeachingDemos::my.symbols` the coordinates of a grid inside the forest areas.

I managed to write a function which plots the symbol:

```
nw <- function(){
  par(oma = c(0,0,0,0), mar = c(0,0,0,0))
  plot(c(-0.84, 0), c(-0.4, 0.67), xlim = c(-1,1), ylim = c(-1,1), type = "l", lwd = 2)
  segments(0, 0.67, 0.84, -0.4, lwd = 4)
}
```

but I didn't manage to pass the function to `my.symbols` in the right way. I also didn't manage to expand a grid only in the forest polygons and thus expanded it over the entire bounding box (`bbox`) of the polygon layer and select only the points lying in the forest. Something like:

```
library(maptools)
nc1 <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
                     proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"))
cd <- c(100, 50)
grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset = nc1@bbox[, 1],
                    cellsize = rep(diff(as.numeric(nc1@bbox["x",]))/100, 2),
                    cells.dim = cd)
grd.sp <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(grd,
                               data = data.frame(id = 1:prod(cd)),
                               proj4string = CRS(proj4string(nc1)))
x11(10, 6)
plot(nc1)
points(coordinates(grd.sp[nc1[which(nc1$AREA > 0.15),],]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Plot a specific image in a delimited polygon

You can use library `sp` to sample points in a specific polygon. In my example, I select a specific polygon according to `NAME`.
Then you can use library `emojifont` to add some symbols from emoji or fontawesome. You can find trees in the list like `evergreen_tree` for instance. Or you can plot your own png image repeatedly.

### Create a regular grid of points in a delimited polygon

So, first create you grid for a specific polygon :

```
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(emojifont)

nc1 <- rgdal::readOGR(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package = "maptools")[1])

# Do a point grid in a specific polygon
grid.pt <- sp::spsample(nc1[which(nc1$NAME == "Alamance"),], n = 20, type = "regular")
```

### Plot emoji as a repeated image pattern

Then plot emoji as text using `grid.pt` :

```
# plot the entire map with restricted limits
plot(nc1, xlim = c(-79.6, -79.1), ylim = c(35.8, 36.3))
# Highlight the selected polygon
plot(nc1[which(nc1$NAME == "Alamance"),], border = "red", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
# Normal points
points(grid.pt, pch = 20, col = "blue", cex = 0.1)
# Add emojifont instead of points
text(coordinates(grid.pt)[, 1], coordinates(grid.pt)[, 2],
  labels = emoji('evergreen_tree'), cex = 1.5,
  col = 'forestgreen', family = 'EmojiOne')
```

[image: Plot emoji as repeated pattern in a delimited polygon]

### Plot you own image as a repeated pattern

You can also use your own png images to be used as points. In this response, an image is downloaded on the web as a reproducible example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118286/is-it-possible-to-create-a-scatterplot-with-icons-svg-or-png-instead-of-points
But, you can create and use your own png image.

```
# Plot with your own image
library(png)
# Image downloaded as an example for reproducibility
iconfile1 <- download.file('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Status-weather-clouds-icon.png',
                           destfile = 'icon1.png', mode = 'wb')
icon1 <- png::readPNG('icon1.png')

# Depending on the desired size of the image
offset <- 0.02

# plot the entire map with restricted limits
plot(nc1, xlim = c(-79.8, -78.9), ylim = c(35.6, 36.5))
# Plot all images at points locations
for (i in 1:length(grid.pt)) {
  graphics::rasterImage(
    icon1, 
    coordinates(grid.pt)[i, 1] - offset,
    coordinates(grid.pt)[i, 2] - offset,
    coordinates(grid.pt)[i, 1] + offset,
    coordinates(grid.pt)[i, 2] + offset
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the second solution one could still mention explicitly what your answer already implies: that one can create their own symbols (as the really simple one in my question), export them to png, and then use them. This workaround with a temporary file isn't as elegant as plain code, but it works already quite good.