# Showing symbol and non-symbol in legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to get a non-standard symbol and a standard symbol in `legend()`.

I'm wondering though, why one of them shows but the other doesn't? Is there a fix to correctly plot this?

Here is my R code:

```
plot(1)
legend("topright", c("Model", "Data"), pch = c("|", 19))
```

[image]

Comment: Because it only admits symbols of 1 length. Check `?legend`:pch 
the plotting symbols appearing in the legend, as numeric vector or a vector of 1-character strings (see points). Unlike points, this can all be specified as a single multi-character string. Must be specified for symbol drawing.

Comment: It seems to be a bit of a pain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159167/r-add-non-pch-symbols-to-a-map-polygon-layer?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. What is possible it to use a 124 which is the numeric coding of the "|"-symbol as well at the 19 to get both "pipe" and solid-dot:

```
legend( "topright", c("Model", "Data"), pch = c(124, 19))
```

[image]